# When I writing php artisan serve 'Class 'reoute' not found'

Tags: laravel-5.3, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

It was working php artisan serve! After its not working! I didn't understand.Did you any suggest to look for it.
And giving error this

[image: This is the screeshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to investigate why this error occurred. You have typo, Check your **app\Http\routes.php** and change **reoute** to **Route**

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your source code. Use your editor (PHPStorm?) to find the word `reoute` in all your project files. It should be, probably route.

Also, make sure you did not modified any of the Laravel files (vendor/laravel/framework). It may be causing this error too.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this! Because it was writing reoute::get('notes/{notes}/edit', 'NotesController@edit'); on web.php. I changed Route::get('notes/{notes}/edit', 'NotesController@edit');

Answer (score 0):

In this error message shows the "reoute" class not found.Then first u should consider about the error message.go to app\Http\routes.php and you can find error.change class reout to Route

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened to me. I've created a laravel project. Until yesterday the `php artisan serve` command was working. Today, I ran the same command and the following error appeared:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
Class 'Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory' not found
```

I solved it by deleting the `vendor` directory and executing the `composer update` command. After that I was able to execute the command `php artisan serve`.